# How to secure using and sharing BigQuery Service account key

Tags: google-bigquery, service-accounts

I want to know what is the best secure way to share and use Service Account key on python .

I share the service account key "JSON File" by email and this not a secured way In addition users use the key in their  code which is something not recommenced by security

Answer (score 0):

while your question doesn't exactly point out your use case, generally, the google cloud secrets is where most secrets can be stored and retrieved.

If you go through this codelabs

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/secret-manager-python#0

this will provide you with approach to using the secrets manager and accessing it in python code.

This is one of preferred approaches in python, however to answer if its is best secure way is based on different use cases - see best practices here

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-service-accounts